# Make rule for man pages (same rule for multiple extensions)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project that contains a library and some applications, and I am including man pages.  I am generating the man pages using ronn, and I have a rule in my makefile that looks like:

```
%.1 : %.1.ronn
    $(RONN) -r $<
```

This works well, and I create the man pages using markdown and ronn happily spits out the man pages.

The problem is that not all of my man pages are for section 1 of the manual.  I would like to put the library pages in section 3, and I may need other sections later as well.  I could define more rules, one for each section, changing the %.1 to %.2, %.3, etc.  I was wondering, though, if there is a way to simply do %.n (where n would match any number or maybe single character), to cut down on the number of rules in my makefile.

Is this possible?  My google results are not showing anything, and nothing I have tried so far has worked.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%` instead of `%.1`, and `%.ronn` instead of `%.1.ronn`.

If you have files `name.1.ronn`, `name.2.ronn`, the `%` will match `name.1` and `name.2`.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work.  It now just says no rule to make target `name.1` when I try to build.  Also, I would still have to create a rule for each output, i.e. %.1, %.2, %.3, etc.  I was hoping to have a single rule for %.n : %.ronn that would match if I have a target that is name.1, name.2, etc.

Comment: Based on your comment you didn't do what 2501 suggested.  It would have been better if they would have provided an explicit example in their answer.  You need to write `% : %.ronn` as the pattern.  If you are trying to make `name.1`, then `%` will match `name.1` and the prerequisite will be `name.1.ronn`.  Etc.  Only one rule is needed.

Comment: Ok, right, I misread.  I simply did not process having a target that was just %.  I have tried it now, and it does work, so thank you for the help.  Somehow having a rule for a target that matches anything makes me look at it sideways, but again, it does work, and doesn't seem to break anything else in my makefile.

Comment: There are issues with match-anything rules; you can read about them in the GNU make manual.  But, they do work and if you don't want to write multiple rules then that's what you have to use.